# How to start a c# winform application project for MC55A0 mobile computer?

Tags: c#, mobile

I am trying to develop a winform application for mobile computers but when I compile project and try to start it on mobile computer, it show a framework error message below.
Which version of microsoft visual studio or framework I need to use.

NOTE: I used visual studio 2010 / 2015 / 2022 and .net framework versions 2.0 and 2.0 < all
Mobile computer uses Windows Operation System

*Error Message:
Sayim.exe
MissingMethodException
File or assembly name 'System.Windows.Forms,Version=2.0.0.0., Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089', or one of its dependencies, was not found.*

Device Information:
Windows Embeded Handheld 6.5 Classic
CE OS 5.2.29344 (Build 29344.5.3.12.401)

Processor: PXA32X-806MHZ
Memory: 232.76 MB

Comment: Please indicate exactly what computer you target (including what OS it has). Basically, .NET Framework is _only_ supported on Windows and .NET Framework 2.0 is really ancient.

Comment: it uses windows os

Comment: Then use at least .NET Framework 4.6, better 4.8 or rather change to .NET 6.0. There shouldn't be a reason to use ancient frameworks if the Operating System is current (Windows 10 or later)

Comment: When I compile it with .net framework 4.8 it says : "To run this application, you must first install one of the following versions of the net compact framework: v4.0.0"

Comment: .NET compact framework is also outdated and no longer supported. Again: Please specify exactly what hardware you have there and what Operating System (Exact name and version number). Without that, we cannot guess which runtime you need for that device.

Comment: Windows Embeded Handheld 6.5 Classic CE OS 5.2.29344

Comment: Ok, maybe somebody can help you with that, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
I installed visual studio 2008 and created a new project as C# smart device and after that selected target platform as windows CE and template device application.
So application works.